# Old version of Thunderbird; when will it be updated?

Tags: thunderbird

I noticed that the current Mozilla version of Thunderbird is much newer than the one installed with Ubuntu. Does anyone know when it'll be updated?

Comment: Hard to tell. You could add the PPA for the beta version of Thunderbird though at https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/thunderbird-next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bug #1575731](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1575731) at Thunderbird's Launchpad account, people have requested for updates to Thunderbird that is available in the official repositories but there is no official response yet. In the meantime, you can add the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/thunderbird-next) for the beta channel of Thunderbird.